# Secure requests to Windows Application behind NAT

Tags: c#, networking, nat

I'm having a windows application that will be deployed on multiple pcs in different networks. This applications need to launch some actions upon receiving appropriate request from external service.

For this, I got `HttpListener` that waits for requests and performs required actions.

The issue is with NAT and security. When windows application starts it needs to tell external service that it's alive and how it can be reached (being behind NAT it's not as trivial, some kind of tunneling is needed?). When external service needs something to be executed on windows application, it sends it a request and application should proceed with actions and send response to the server.

What is the best way to expose my Windows Application behind NAT to external service (tunneling?) and how to make it secure (HTTPS?)? Or, maybe, there is a better solution for this kind of remote calls (RPC?)?

Answer (score 0):

Sending http requests to clients behind NAT means, that you have to manually create a route in your NAT router for each client that forwards a port on the external IP to a fixed internal IP.

To make it secure, you have two options:

- Use TLS (https) = each client needs a cert and accept https
- Leave the requests insecure but keep them in a "secure environment". This could be done with an VPN connection between your server and the NAT network (while defining the local network as secure).

Such a setup works fine if you want to run a server application (one host) and are willing to invest some time. It will typically shorten your life if you want to do that with a large amount of client applications in a company network.

There are technologies available to send messages to clients without having to configure anything on routers. For .Net we have SignalR which combines multiple approaches and uses "the best possible": https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: Thank you for your response, Christoph. I would love to have the solution without port forwarding if possible. Isn't it possible to do tunneling like it's done using e.g. `ngrok` which doesn't require opening any ports or configurint NAT?

Comment: Yes you can also create a tunnel to some server (if IT department allows you to do it) but I'm not aware of any lib that would make that easy.